# javascript filereader lags from my homepage but not on jsbin

Tags: javascript, optimization, filereader, lag

I have a homepage where a user can upload an image from their computer and preview it on my homepage, only problem is that uploading images > 0.5MB takes 10+ seconds. I copy/pasted everything from here (my html is EXACTLY like this)

http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/edit#javascript,html,live

the jsbin example loads very quickly while mine remaines non-responsive for 10+ seconds.

Has anybody else experienced a long loading time when using javascript's FileReader()? Any ideas why my homepage handles the upload so dismally?

Thanks

Comment: @ChrisMorgan http://64.71.143.174/persona/

Comment: Now you've changed it... from what it was, though, I would strongly recommend that you take a look at how it feels in Firefox. Your technique of masking the file input doesn't work very well there. Not sure about other browsers, though, because you changed it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan i just changed it back to the jsbin. sorry was developing stuff. I noticed that the lag only happens on chrome, mozilla works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem was setting `$('#image').attr('src',longlonglonglongdataurl);`especially for large images so once i loaded the image onto a javascript variable and listened for the .onload(), i drew the image onto a canvas and cropped it to the exact dimension that i needed it at (reducing the dataurl length).

works for me, hope this helps others